# Drag the Gridview column and drop to another Form TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, drag-and-drop

I want to drag column from `Form1.Gridview` and drop it on `Form2.TextBox`. When
dropped on `Form2.Textbox`, the textbox should show the column name of dropped item.

The scenario:

1. First Form1 shows to the user.
2. User clicks on Form2 button.

3 .Form2 shows to the user.

4. User drags the `LastName` column from `Form1.GridView`
5. Drop it on `Form2.TextBox`
6. `Form2.TextBox` must show the dropped column name

Maybe following image make it clearer:

[image]

Please let me know how can I do that, I looked on some code but didn't understand

Comment: Anybody anything ????

Comment: hey nobody knows the solution?